# JavaScript, iterate class and on click show hidden tr

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, addeventlistener

No jQuery.
I want to loop through unknown amount of table rows with the same class and add a click event that will change the class of hidden table row that is right bellow the one i clicked. All i managed to do is open all hidden rows on click..

Here is a fiddle with my current progres: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mpasd/sf90d6c5/2/)

An my js code, that obviously doesn't work...

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.table');
var y = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
      if (i === j) {
        y[j].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

EDIT:
Also i saw that it is bad to make functions inside loops. Would appreciate some feedback on that as well...

Comment: What exactly u want on click of any tr if it Class "table" then next content tr will be show ? This u want

Comment: Click on table row with class table and show the appropriate table row that is hidden bellow it. But i can't figure out how to match them...

Comment: why dont u use jquery ?

Comment: $(".table").click(function() { 
  $(this).closest("tr.content").next().show();
});

Comment: @Kashyap - At the moment i want to learn about pure js. So please, no jQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`nextElementSibling`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_nextelementsibling.asp) function

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sf90d6c5/5/)**

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.table');

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       this.nextElementSibling.style.display='block';
    });
}
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

table {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
}

.table:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.content.visible {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Tabela</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr class="table">
          <td>Visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="content">
          <td>Hidden 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table">
          <td>Visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="content">
          <td>Hidden 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table">
          <td>Visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="content">
          <td>Hidden 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table">
          <td>Visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="content">
          <td>Hidden 4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**or** If you need like **`toggle  effect`** (reclick to hide) use this js code

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.table');

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var a = this.nextElementSibling.style.display;
        this.nextElementSibling.style.display = (a == 'block') ? 'none': 'block';

    });
}
```

Comment: Thats it. Marked as answer... Thank you.